# What if I change my choice for the accepted answer, move the green tick, and remove my earlier upvote?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

Let’s say I post a question and a user answers it. I then mark it as the accepted answer and upvote it.

What happens to the user reputation if I remove the green tick from
his/her answer and remove the upvote?

Does it change his/her reputation points?

Also, when I accept another answer, will the poster of that answer receive reputation points?

In other words, what happens when I move the green tick from one answer to another?

Comment: "will the new accepted *question* ... receive reputation points" - did you mean "accepted *answer*"?

Comment: Note that you cannot remove an upvote unless the post is edited. Also, why would you also remove the upvote? I mean if it was useful at one point that you even accepted it as an answer, what changed in the quality of the post?

Comment: Accidents happen.  Assuming you are human, you might accidentally click upvote while scrolling or performing another action.  You can remove an up or down vote for a small window of time.  After that grace period, your vote will be locked until the post is edited (by anyone).

Comment: I am a strong advocate for moving the green tick when something truly better is posted. There is a "sting" delivered to the user that posted the initially accepted answer, but if you are shifting the green tick for legitimate/non-trivial reasons, you are actually doing that user a favor.  They lose 15pts (no big deal), but what they gain is the awareness that there is a better way to learn from -- in this case EVERYBODY wins: OP, the tick-loser, the tick-winner is rewarded justifiably for their attention to a seemingly "resolved" page, and future researchers will be ushered to the best answer.

Comment: ...there was a yearning in my heart to further explain my stance beyond what would sensibly fit in a comment.  (I've been wanting to express it for a long time.  It feels good to type it all out.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**FYI**

- When you accept any answer, the user will be rewarded with 15 points and the user who has asked the question will be rewarded with 2 points.
- When you upvote any answer (or question) the user will be rewarded with 10 points.

> What happens to the user reputation if I remove his accepted answer and remove upvote?

- When you un-accept an answer:
  The user who posted the answer will lose 15 points from his reputation and the user who asked the question will also lose 2 points from his reputation.
- When you remove any upvote from any answer (or question), the user loses 10 points from his reputation.

**NOTE :** No effect on your reputation if you remove upvote from any post, you cannot remove votes after five minutes unless the post has been edited, while
you can accept and un-accept answers at any time.

> Does it change his reputation points?

**Yes**

> Also will the new accepted question that I will select receive reputation points?

Check this [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 8):

The truth is, as [Nilesh has stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370053/what-if-i-remove-the-accepted-answer-and-upvote/370054#370054), that there will be a rep point loss to the user that you remove an upvote(-10) or accepted answer(-15) from.  Perhaps I should clarify that you get +2 for accepting, then -2 for unaccepting (retracted rep points), then +2 for accepting the post again or another answer (so long as it's not your own).

That said, I would like to suggest a perspective shift.  Try to separate yourself from what is "good/bad" for individual users, and focus instead on what is "good/bad" for Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites)...

Some users have "***SOheretohelp***" in their profiles, I think it should be "***heretohelpSO***" and here's why...

If you award a green tick to an answer, then a "better" answer comes along (10 minutes later, 1 week later, 3 years later) then by not moving the green tick, you are doing a great disservice.

*IMPORTANT: Let me be very clear that moving the green tick for trivial/illegitimate reasons will cause unnecessary damage/chaos.  If you are moving the green tick purely because of code styling (procedural vs object-oriented, micro-optimization where not explicitly asked for, etc.) then that will very likely lead to outrage and an ongoing cutthroat environment in the community.  ...back to my points...

Who loses when you don't move the green tick?

1. **You, the asker**, because:

- it may be interpreted (by future researchers or future employers) that you don't know the difference between a working solution and an optimal solution
- you are sending a message that once you have a working solution, you will not honor users who graciously volunteer their time and express their superior expertise to you.

2. **The initial green tick recipient**, because:

- if they knew a better way to solve the issue, they were either sloppy, hasty ([FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)), or under-motivated to deliver it on the day.
- if they don't know a better way to solve the issue, they are likely to carry on delivering the sub-optimal advice throughout the community. (preserved/reinforced ignorance)

3. **The late poster**, because:

- they have generously supplied a superior answer for the benefit of all, but are not duly rewarded for their attention/expertise simply because they:

  1. live in a different time zone from you and were possibly asleep
  2. didn't see your question because they were pre-occupied (helping others, reviewing, working, or otherwise "having a life offline")
  3. took longer to craft a more considered, polished, and educational post.
- they will learn that that answering "resolved" questions is "not worth it" in terms of "magical unicorn points".

4. **The community/researchers**, because:

- volunteers will be less likely to visit "resolved" questions with the intention to offer support, and so the site becomes packed with speed-posted solutions rather than professional-grade answers and the overall quality of the site is diminished.
- the highest quality answer does not wear the "giant, green eyeball-grabber" so additional study-time is necessary to determine why an answer that *seems* better is not designated as such.

I'll avoid repeating the inverse of the above itemized list, but essentially, by reversing all of those losses -- we all enjoy all of those wins.

... back to the personal/user level thinking.  Reputation points are one of the *loose* metrics for gauging "trust" and "expertise" within this community.  Privileges are provided to volunteers who prove themselves to possess tag-related talents.  Depriving these diligent volunteers of their well-earned accolades is disheartening.

What specifically do I suggest?

If anyone gives you a solution that was useful/correct and it was helpful to you, upvote that post and never remove the upvote.

If someone speed-posts a low-quality, unexplained, code-only, incomplete answer then "hold out".  Ask them to improve their answer and/or wait until someone else does and only award the green tick when you are completely satisfied.

If someone posts a cleaner, more direct, more professional-grade, more educational answer that is superior to the currently accepted answer, give credit where credit is due and shift the green tick.

If you don't know if one answer is superior to another, then ASK!  Leave a comment to both posters and seek clarification.  This helps you to determine if there were previously undiscovered vulnerabilities or performance improvements.  This also makes both users aware of both posts and they can compare and learn from them.  When you have a sincere, thoughtful, respectful dialogue *and* you move the green tick, you are less likely to cause undue distress among volunteers.

I'll predict at least one comment to this answer that will state that the green tick does not *mean* that a question is "resolved" and that the green tick does not *mean* "this is the best answer".  While it is documented that the green tick does not signify these meanings, the human psyche is going to make an intuitive assumption anyhow that these meanings are more-or-less true.  I think we may as well ride that assumption.  ...at least until the green tick is downsized and less visually impactful (like the blue bounty indicator).

---

Have I personally ever lost 15 points because of a moved tick?  Yes.  And how did I react?  I rushed to that page to discover the cause.  One time, I was outperformed by another poster -- the tick-shift was legitimate.  I then studied the issue harder.  I spent more time researching and developing and refined my answer to then supply a new, more superior answer to the newly accepted answer.  I contacted the OP, explained my changes and re-earned the green tick -- everybody wins because content quality improved (and I learned to raise my game).  Another time, I posted a regular expression answer and that post was unaccepted because a better (unbeatable) pattern was provided.  When I read the other answer, I learned a completely new "trick" -- I wasn't a "loser", I was a "learner".  I'll be honest, if learning excellent new tricks costs me 15 rep points every once in a while, I'll gladly pay that and say "*Thank you sir, may I have another?*".  And if the threat of losing a green tick looms, then people just may think twice before dropping a half-cooked answer from their phone at a bus stop.

I am arguing for the greater good here.  Invariably, there will be those who will have a distaste for my policy.  I am willing to cop flack / downvotes for my stance (or I have no business posting on Meta).